# Trying to generate a CSS file in wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I want to dynamically create a file in the wordpress uploads folder when the user saves values of some custom fields. this is what i try but the file won't be written:

```
function generate_options_css() {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $ss_dir = get_stylesheet_directory();
    ob_start(); // Capture all output into buffer
    require($ss_dir . '/custom-styles.php'); // Grab the custom-style.php file
    $css = ob_get_clean(); // Store output in a variable, then flush the buffer
    file_put_contents($upload_dir . '/custom-styles.css', $css, LOCK_EX); // Save it as a css file
}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'generate_options_css' ); //Parse the output and write the CSS file on post save
```

Comment: Does the web user have sufficient write permissions to the target folder?

Comment: Hmm, any idea how to give the user write permissions. in the previous version i have written the file to the theme folder, that worked without a problem.

Comment: Depends on what OS your server is running

Comment: Every project is on another shared hoster.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_css() {
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); 
$base_dir = wp_get_upload_dir(); 
$styles = wp_get_custom_css();
if ( $styles || is_customize_preview() ) :
$type_attr = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'style' ) ? '' : ' type="text/css"';

$file = file_put_contents($upload_dir['basedir']."/new-style-function.css", strip_tags( $styles ) );
move_uploaded_file($file, $upload_dir['baseurl']);

endif;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_custom_css' );

$upload_path = wp_upload_dir(); 
wp_enqueue_style ('custom-style',$upload_path['baseurl'] .'/new-style-function.css');
```

Comment: Please provide some feedback in your answer about what you have fixed

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.